# Is there a concept of "merit of the mothers"?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, imahot-matriarch-mothers

There is a familiar concept called zechus avos, that the merits of our forefathers can have an impact on later generations (see Shabbat 55a) or maaseh avos siman l'banim, which is roughly equivalent (see Ramban on Bereshis 12:6).

Does the equivalent concept exist for the imahot: Sarah, Rifka, Rachel and Leah?

Comment: How do you know that avos doesn't include the imahot?

Comment: It doesnt sound equivalent at all to me. Maybe I should check the ramban.

Answer (score 6):

> ב'שפת אמת' (פסח תרמ'ב) כותב, כי חלקה של זכות אמהות רב משל זכות אבות, כפי שאמרו חז'ל (ראש השנה יא ע'א): ''מדלג על ההרים' – בזכות אבות, 'מקפץ על הגבעות' – בזכות אמהות'. ומסיים שם, שאף שאומרת הגמרא (שבת נה ע'ב) שתמה זכות אבות – עם כל זאת, זכות אמהות לא תמה. 'כן יעשה לנו עתה בזכות האמהות', עיי'ש.‏

—http://www.mercazharav.org.il/default.asp?pg=3&id=869

So the answer from the sfas emmes (pesach 5642) is that the equivalent concept also exists for the imahos. And its even greater than the zchus ovos. We know this since the gmoro says that zchus ovos has already finished, meaning is used up, but even so the zchus imahos hasn't and whatever hashem has done for us in zchus ovos he will now do in zchus imahaos.

Comment: Comments on this answer were many and obsolete and have been preserved in [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9442/comments-from-post-28308).